# COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder<num>/server/requirements.txt: no such file or directory

Tags: django, azure, docker, azure-devops, azure-container-service

Appears to be some kind of context issue. I'm trying to figure out why this would work fine when spinning up a local Kubernetes cluser with Skaffold, but is failing to build the image properly when pushing to Azure.

Basic structure is:

```
test-app/
  server/
    requirements.txt
    Dockerfile
azure-pipeline.yml
skaffold.yaml
```

I have the production `server/Dockerfile` as the following:

```
FROM python:3.7-slim
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
WORKDIR '/app'
EXPOSE 5000
COPY ./server/requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY ./server .
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "collectstatic"]
CMD ["gunicorn", "-b", ":5000", "--log-level", "info", "config.wsgi:application"]
```

I'm using the `azure-pipelines.yml` that was generated for me in the Pipelines section of Azure DevOps:

```
# Docker
# Build and push an image to Azure Container Registry
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/docker

trigger:
- master

resources:
- repo: self

variables:
  # Container registry service connection established during pipeline creation
  dockerRegistryServiceConnection: '<connection-string>'
  imageRepository: 'testapp'
  containerRegistry: 'testappcontainers.azurecr.io'
  dockerfilePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/server/Dockerfile'
  tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'

  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build and push stage
  jobs:  
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build and push an image to container registry
      inputs:
        command: buildAndPush
        repository: $(imageRepository)
        dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)
        containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
        tags: |
          $(tag)
```

During the automated build it gets to `COPY ./server/requirements.txt .` and the throws the error in the title.

Reading [this question](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/1922), I've tried a number of the suggested solutions with no resolution, like:

```
COPY ./server/requirements.txt /app
COPY server/requirements.txt /app
```

In addition, I've also just tried:

```
COPY requirements.txt /app
```

Still get the error.

So, kind of stumped on:

1. How to resolve this so it builds correctly in Pipelines and pushes to CRS...
2. If it is a context issue, why isn't an issue in local dev when using Skaffold

---

Actually, the [example project](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/pipelines-javascript-docker) has a similar project structure:

```
pipelines-javascript-docker/
  app/
    Dockerfile
```

And it runs fine... some I'm probably overlooking something apparently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at the example project more closely, which has the same structure as what I'm trying to do, I ended up copying its `Dockerfile` formatting. I ended up with this which is working fine:

```
FROM python:3.7-slim
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5000
COPY requirements*.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "collectstatic"]
CMD ["gunicorn", "-b", ":5000", "--log-level", "info", "config.wsgi:application"]
```

Answer (score 3):

When I encountered this obstacle I resolved by setting up the property **buildContext** in the yml file.

```
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Build and push an image to container registry
  inputs:
    containerRegistry: '$(ACR.Connector)'
    repository: '$(imageName)'
    command: 'buildAndPush'
    Dockerfile: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/s/server/Dockerfile'
    buildContext: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/s'
    tags: '$(tag)'
```

Comment: solved it for me as well in azure pipeline build of .netCore 3 app in linux container